# Mobile browser displays different than Chrome using F12

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to build a static website with multiple checkboxes, but the CSS only works on chrome (using F12 to see how it displays on a mobile), there is a trouble displaying the website on my Iphone (the checkboxes doesn't follow `display: inline-block`)

Here is the code I used:

HTML

```
<div class="checkboxContainer">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">label1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">label2</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .checkboxContainer {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
    .checkboxContainer label {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

How it looks on chrome using F12 displaying on iPhone XR:
[image]

How it looks on my iPhone:
[image]

Comment: Chrome's developer tools are not meant to be an emulator. System- or Browser-version-specific differences may still exist. Are you using Chrome or Safari on the real phone? You may have to find a tutorial for remote debugging of the browser on the phone.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I have tried to use Chrome and Safari, both looked the same. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: The problem might be the css and media query.  For all screen sizes, labels should be "nowrap" to keep text and checkbox together. And for all screen sizes, the container should be "wrap" to prevent the checkboxes from extending beyond the edge of the screen.  Try these tests on your iPhone: [Original Code](https://jsfiddle.net/qmw2y6Lz/show) and [Modified Code](https://jsfiddle.net/qmw2y6Lz/1/show)

Comment: @Yogi I have tried both on my phone they displayed in the same way(the correct one), then I tried it on my web but after pushing it up to GitHub pages, it displays the same way, maybe there is something wrong with something else